# Android - Insert row into SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have problem with inserting row into db table. I've following code:

```
try {
  myDB = jDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).db;

  myDB.beginTransaction();
  String sSQL = "INSERT INTO kosik (mnozstvi, cena, idVyrobek) VALUES ('" +
          sMn + "', '" + sCena + "', '" + String.valueOf(iIDVyrobku) + "');";
  myDB.execSQL(sSQL, null);
  myDB.endTransaction();
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Class jDB is following:

```
public class jDB {
private static jDB dbInstance = null;
public static String DB_PATH;
public static SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.sqlite";
.
.
.
public static jDB getInstance(Context context)
{
if (dbInstance  == null) 
{
  DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName();
  // if not exists database, copy new from assets
  if (!isDataBaseExist())
  {
    try {
      copyDataBase(context);
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
      Toast.makeText(context,
          "" + ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
  DB_PATH = DB_PATH + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;
  db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
  // create singleton object
  dbInstance = new jDB(context);
}
return dbInstance;
}
```

After insert, everything seems OK, but no row is inserted into table...

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks, Petr

SOLUTION:

Finally, there is working solution:

```
try {
    myDB = jDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).db;

    myDB.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
    insertValues.put("idVyrobek", String.valueOf(iIDVyrobku));
    insertValues.put("mnozstvi", sMn);
    insertValues.put("cena", sCena);
    insertValues.put("poznamka", "");
    myDB.insertOrThrow("kosik", null, insertValues);
    myDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
  } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    myDB.endTransaction();
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help Bismark  !

Answer (score 1):

Try to add setTransactionSuccessful() before call endTransaction(). Also I usually put the endTransaction at finally statement to avoid issues with SQLite:

```
myDB = jDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).db;
myDB.beginTransaction();
try {
    String sSQL = "INSERT INTO kosik (mnozstvi, cena, idVyrobek) VALUES ('" +
          sMn + "', '" + sCena + "', '" + String.valueOf(iIDVyrobku) + "');";
    myDB.execSQL(sSQL, null);
    myDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    myDB.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Yes, setTransactionSuccessful() was one piece in puzzle :-)